# How to select a particular word from a feature

Tags: python, string, pandas

I am implementing feature extraction using value_counts to display maximum number of repeated strings , but I want to extract a particular word and assign the value 1 to the word which is appeared and other NaN values must be filled with 0. What I am doing right now is I am searching that word manually in the string and then mapping the string with 1 and filling the NaN values with 0 using fillna(0).

```
print(train.key_skills.value_counts(), '\n')

train['key_skills'] = train['key_skills'].map({
    'Linear Regression, Insurance Analytics, Business Analysis..':1,
    'Linear Regression, Insurance Analytics, Business Analysis...':1,
    'Analytics, SAS, banking, insurance, Analytics Head':1,
    'NoSQL, Spark, Mapreduce, SQL, Cassandra, Data Science, SCALA, Big Data...':1,
    'NoSQL, Spark, Mapreduce, SQL, Cassandra, Data Science, SCALA, Big Data...':1,
    'Excel, SQL, Data Analysis, Segmentation, SAS, Data Mining, SPSS...':1,
    'Linear Regression, Business Analysis, Model Development, Segmentation, Base...':1,
    'Data analysis, SQL, Consulting, Data management, SPSS, FMCG, Analytical...':1,
    'Data Analytics, Business Intelligence, Communication Protocols...':1,
    'r, advanced analytics, segmentation, sas, machine learning...':1,
    'Data Analytics, Data Science, Predictive Modeling, Project Management...':1,
    'NLP, Neural Networks, Machine Learning, Data Mining...':1,
    'Text Mining, Hive, NoSQL, Python, R, SQL, Data Analysis, Machine Learning...':1,
    'Data Science, R, Machine Learning, Linear Regression, Cluster Analysis...':1,
    'Retail Analytics, Analytics, clustering, segmentation, ranking, correlation...':1,
    'Linear Regression, SAS, Data Analytics, Correlation, Statistics, analytic...':1,
    'Analytics, Machine Learning, TensorFlow, Pytorch, python libraries...':1,
    'Data Analytics, SQL, Statistics, R, Econometrics, Data Mining...':1,
    'Quant Analytics, Analytics, Data Analysis, Sentiment Analysis...':1,
    'machine learning, text mining, r, python, neural networks, sql, sas...':1,
    'Predictive Modeling, Logistic Regression, R, SAS, Predictive Analytics...':1,
    'Business Analyst, Data Analytics, R, Python, MATLAB, SQL, Machine Learning,...':1,
    'Business Analyst, Data Analytics, R, Python, MATLAB, SQL, Machine Learning,...':1,
    'Retail Analytics, Business Analysis, Excel, SAS, Data Analytics, VBA...':1,
    'Deep Learning, R, Machine Learning, Python, Stakeholder Management...':1,
    'Hadoop, Java, Data Science, Cloudera, Spark, Hive, Impala, Presales...':1,
    'SQL, Javascript, Automation, Python, Ruby, Analytics, Machine learning...':1,
    'machine learning, team leading, Analytics, Natural Language Processing...':1,
    'Analytics, Data Science, Program Delivery, Solutioning, Presales, Proposals...':1,
    'NLP, SAS, User Stories, Agile Development, Machine Learning, Test Scenarios...':1,
    'Analytics, Head - Analytics, data analytics, Data Science, business process...':1,
    'Java, SCALA, Spring, Python, Solr, Redis, Machine Learning, Algorithms, Web...':1,
    'Deep Learning, NLP, Spark, Information Retrieval, Java, Python...':1,
    'SCALA, Machine Learning, Java, Python, SQL, R, Pig, Data Mining, Perl...':1
})
```

Here I either want a code that should map the word Data Scientist wherever in the string by 1 where it is not appearing it should should put 0.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to map manually, just use [str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) along with [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['train_skills'] = [
        'Linear Regression, Insurance Analytics, Business Analysis..',
        'Linear Regression, Insurance Analytics, Business Analysis...',
        'Analytics, SAS, banking, insurance, Analytics Head',
        'NoSQL, Spark, Mapreduce, SQL, Cassandra, Data Science, SCALA, Big Data...',
        'NoSQL, Spark, Mapreduce, SQL, Cassandra, Data Science, SCALA, Big Data...',
        np.nan]

###### THE LINE OF CODE YOU NEED ######
df['train_skills'] = np.where(df.train_skills.str.contains('Data Science'), 1, 0)
```

Output:

```
   train_skills
0             0
1             0
2             0
3             1
4             1
5             1
```

Comment: I was about to ans. you first. +1 :-)